# Display Time taken at each screen on last screen

Tags: time, justinmind

I am working in justinmind.  I want to display time taken at each screen on my last screen.  I have already displayed time on each screen separately(it will show system time). for example.

Screen 1 - timing 4:55:44
Screen 2 - timing 5:32:43
Screen 3 - timing 5:32:56

now, i need to show time log as i have mentioned above on a separate screen.

Answer (score 0):

Save the "System hour" expression to a variable On load of the screen1, then OnUnload of Screen 1 save current time into different variable using same procedure.
Then get the difference between both times.
Then use a text to display time.